# loading data from json files

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Im trying to figure something out. If I want to load JSON data from a local file in my angular app, is there a way for me to include or to read the file in angular, or do I need to use some file API to read from the file and store the objects in a array. ty

Comment: show code of what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $http for loading json data from json file

```
var name = angular.module("app", []);

name.controller("ctrlu", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
        {    
            $http.get('js/data.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.guitarVariable = data;
        });

        }]
);
```

Note:you don't need to include(reference) json file in index.html page

Comment: man thats right! ... i was totally zoning out, not considering the ajax calls...of course i can get them locally. dumb question dough. thanks man

Comment: i think without ajax call you can't get json data from json file.

Comment: could i use something like $http.put to update vales in the file? or then i need file api?

Comment: in that case you need file api